# how do I fix "com.unity.burst aborted"

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I get this error when I start a URP project it loads for 5 to 6 minutes then this error appears

Answer (score 1):

Delete your manifest.json file.

A new one should be automatically created when you relaunch Unity, which hopefully fixes the problem.